# Ionic - Use Cordova-plugin-mqtt

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, mqtt

I'm trying to make an app to allow my phone (Android but I'm trying to aim both Android and IOS) to subscribe to MQTT topics. I found this plugin : https://github.com/arcoirislabs/cordova-plugin-mqtt that fit my needs because it use tcp:// and not mqtt:// which is what I need.

But here is the problem :

I think I don't know how to install properly the plugin or how to use it because in my file app.module.ts I wrote :

```
import {CordovaMqTTPlugin} from 'cordova-plugin-mqtt';
```

But my text editor (Sublime Text 3) underlined `'cordova-plugin-mqtt'` in red and say "Cannot find module 'cordova-plugin-mqtt' "

Any suggestions ?

Thank you

EDIT : I aslo tried to use it like this :

`declare let cordova:any;`

`constructor(...){
  platform.ready().then(()=> {
  cordova.plugins.CordovaMqTTPlugin.connect(...);});
}`

Comment: Did you find any solution to resolve your issue? I m facing the same message ...

Answer (score 0):

You'd have to add the cordova plugin into your project's configuration, by doing this:

ionic cordova plugin add (the plugin you need)

e.g.
ionic cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-mqtt

Answer (score 0):

The Plugin of `cordova-plugin-mqtt` already including in `cordova.js`. you just need call it on your `index.html` through :

`<script src="cordova.js"></script>`